# Why we address registers in micro-controller programming like this

Tags: c, arm, embedded, microcontroller

why when we write address for register we add offset to the the base address?

Also why do we write the syntax like this below

```
#define CGPIO  (*((volatile unsigned long*)0x400FE608));
```

I mean the pointer part syntax only

Comment: "We" don't write it like this if we know C well enough. And this is no tutoring site. What is your **specific** problem you don't find answered in a C book or a simple tutorial?

Comment: `#define CGPIO =`? Are you sure you meant to have that `=` in your `#define`?

Comment: @PCLuddite: And still "we" don't write it like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `(volatile unsigned long*)0x400FE608` syntax casts a hardware-specific address in memory, presumably of a register, to pointer to `volatile unsigned long`. The type of the pointer, `volatile unsigned long`, is based on the size of the register, and the need to treat it as unsigned. The pointer is defined to point to `volatile` to ensure that the compiler does not optimize multiple reads and writes, performing an operation each time your code requires it.

The asterisk in front and parentheses around the whole expression is so that you can treat `CGPIO` as if it were an assignable global variable, and write

```
CGPIO = 123;
```

and

```
unsigned long val = CGPIO;
```

without adding an asterisk in front of `CGPIO`.

Comment: thanks for your explanation that was helpful but what about the second asterisk?

Comment: @alain: correct, I've edited to be (I think) correct.

Comment: @user247954 The second asterisk makes the cast a cast to a pointer, as opposed to a cast to `unsigned long`.

Comment: Using standard integer types is still a very bad idea. No sane embedded developer would use them. There is a reason for `stdint.h` fixed width types.

Answer (score 1):

It is a trick or side effect or intentional part of the language that allows you to create pointers that you can use to access (read or write) physical addresses.  Generally done this way for control and status registers for peripherals.  If it were a bank of memory you could do the same thing too of course.

It is not the only way to do it and I have had it fail to produce the right sized transfer, but it works way way more often than it doesnt.  It is an extremely common thing to find in chip vendors open source bare metal drivers.